# I'm trying to create an ai chatbot using electron and python. code is working properly but in js part their is problem

Tags: javascript, python, file-io, file-handling, kaggle

I'm experiencing difficulties with file handling and interfacing between Python and JavaScript in my code hosted on Kaggle. The code, accessible https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/swastikpandey0813/my-code this link, contains paths for file operations.

My goal is to establish a workflow where:

1. js takes user input and writes it to a file.
2. Python processes the input, writes the response to another file.
3. JavaScript reads the response file and performs operations.
4. All files are deleted and recreated for the next iteration.
5. Despite multiple attempts, the JavaScript component fails to read
   the output file generated by 6)Python and execute subsequent tasks.
   I've tried adjusting file paths and permissions without success.

Could someone provide guidance on properly implementing this workflow, ensuring seamless interaction between Python and JavaScript for file handling?

I appreciate any insights, code snippets, or suggestions.

Comment: so, in step 5, javascript fails to read the files deleted in step 4? You may need to show some actual code, since your vague description is not helping describe your vague issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)